# How to make addEventListener work for Javascript functions in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I currently have `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', functionName);` which passes the following function as the parameter:

```js
function functionName() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/populatePage',
    success: function(data) {
      createPage(data);
    }
  })
}
```

**Problem Description:**

When the function above is in the same javascript file as the line `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', functionName);` the page loads properly.

But when the function is saved in a separate javascript file and then included in the file with the line above, the page does not load.

I'm probably missing something basic here, but can anyone please explain?

Comment: Did you load js file containing `functionName` after `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', functionName);`?

Comment: I have loaded it before

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No console errors that I can see. But as a note I am using a main.handlebars that includes all the necessary javascript

Comment: Try adding some debug statements to verify your load order of the JavaScript.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks for the tip! It was the javascript load order!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it global function.
It's not advisable but if you want quick solution then

```
window.functionName = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/populatePage',
    success: function(data) {
      createPage(data);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: it should be by default. He said he got no console erros (hence no function undefined errors)

Comment: It was the javascript load order. Thanks for the help. Marking this as resolved